# How to write inline Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a change event handler in JS, but I want to write it inline in the HTML. How can I write the below action as inline like `onchange="javascript: function() { return false; };"`?

```js
function changed(element) {
  if (element.value == 1 || element.value == 2) {
    $(element).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="chosen" name="content_media" style="width: 200px; display: none;" onchange="changed(this)" required="">
  <option value="default">--Select--</option>
  <option value="0">Press Ad</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
  <option value="5">option5</option>
  <option value="6">option6</option>
  <option value="7">option7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why inline when you can have event handler?jquery is not the correct tag for inline

Comment: Not a direct answer to your issue, but don't use inline event handlers. Unobtrusive event handlers are *by far* the better standard to follow.

Comment: Don't use inline styles either...

Comment: in my case only  add and remove classes so i choose inline event handler@guradio

Comment: Still not a good reason to use inline handlers. Always use unobtrusive unless you logically are unable to. Also, I'm very confused as to how you raise a change event on a select that's hidden, which will then show itself? The logic makes little sense.

Comment: Code snippet shows nothing due to `display: none;`. Sad!

Comment: One-word pejoratives? Is Trump on SO now?! @PeterB it has `display: none` in the `style` tag in the example code

Comment: Why? Makes the code harder to maintain and to debug. A completely backwards idea

Comment: @TJ except, of course in html e-mails

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the javascript code, example:

```
onchange="alert('Value was changed to ' + event.target.value);"
```

This might make your code messier though...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery it's better to attach your event in the js side instead of inline-events, like :

```js
$('.chosen').on('change', function(){
  var selected_value = $(this).val();

  if ( selected_value == 1 || selected_value == 2 )
     console.log(selected_value+' selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="chosen" name="content_media" style="width: 200px;" required="">
  <option value="default">--Select--</option>
  <option value="0">Press Ad</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
  <option value="5">option5</option>
  <option value="6">option6</option>
  <option value="7">option7</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.